# I can't display the option of select in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

If I put the javascript on the html file it displayed, like this:

```
<select class="inputField" id="selectTopping0" ></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myDiv = document.getElementById("selectTopping0");
    var dishArray = [
{id:0, name: "Beef Teriyaki", type: "mainDish", price:100},
{id:1, name: "Onigiri", type: "sideDish", price: 80},
{id:2, name: "Miso Soup", type: "soup", price: 50},
{id:3, name: "Vegetable Soup", type: "soup", price: 40},
{id:4, name: "Kinpira Gobo", type: "sideDish", price: 70},
{id:5, name: "Chicken Katsu", type: "mainDish", price: 110},];
for (i = 0; i < dishArray.length; i++) {
    // create an option that will be added to the 'dishSelect'
    if ('sideDish' == dishArray[i].type) {
        var optionItem = document.createElement("option");
        optionItem.text = dishArray[i].name;
        optionItem.setAttribute("value", dishArray[i].id);
        optionItem.setAttribute("data-price", dishArray[i].price);
        optionItem.setAttribute("data-type", dishArray[i].type);
        myDiv.add(optionItem);
    }
}</script>
```

but when I put it in a .js file, it doesn't display properly anymore, like this:

**bentoCustomize.js**

```
function initCustomizeBentoScreen() {
console.log("bentoCustomize.initCustomizeBentoScreen" + " start");
    document.getElementById("bentoName").value = "";
    var mainDishSelect = document.getElementById("selectTopping0");
    populateSelect(mainDishSelect, "mainDish");
    mainDishSelect.selectedIndex = 0;

console.log("bentoCustomize.initCustomizeBentoScreen" + " end");
}

function populateSelect(dishSelect, distType){
console.log("bentoCustomize.populateSelect" + "start");

            // Create and append the options
            for (var i = 0; i < dishArray.length; i++) {

                if(dishArray[i].type == distType){
                    var optionItem = document.createElement("option");
                    optionItem.text = dishArray[i].name;
                    optionItem.setAttribute("value", dishArray[i].id);
                    optionItem.setAttribute("data-price", dishArray[i].price);
                    optionItem.setAttribute("data-type", dishArray[i].type);
                    dishSelect.add(optionItem);
                }


            }


console.log("bentoCustomize.populateSelect " + "end");
}
```

the array is in another js file **bentoMain.js**

```
var dishArray = [
{id:0, name: "Beef Teriyaki", type: "mainDish", price:100},
{id:1, name: "Onigiri", type: "sideDish", price: 80},
{id:2, name: "Miso Soup", type: "soup", price: 50},
{id:3, name: "Vegetable Soup", type: "soup", price: 40},
{id:4, name: "Kinpira Gobo", type: "sideDish", price: 70},
{id:5, name: "Chicken Katsu", type: "mainDish", price: 110},    
];
```

array is not inside any function

**view.html**

```
<script src="../js/bentoMain.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bentoCustomize.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myDiv = document.getElementById("selectTopping0");
    var dishArray = [
{id:0, name: "Beef Teriyaki", type: "mainDish", price:100},
{id:1, name: "Onigiri", type: "sideDish", price: 80},
{id:2, name: "Miso Soup", type: "soup", price: 50},
{id:3, name: "Vegetable Soup", type: "soup", price: 40},
{id:4, name: "Kinpira Gobo", type: "sideDish", price: 70},
{id:5, name: "Chicken Katsu", type: "mainDish", price: 110},];
      
      for (i = 0; i < dishArray.length; i++) {
    // create an option that will be added to the 'dishSelect'
    if ('sideDish' == dishArray[i].type) {
        var optionItem = document.createElement("option");
        optionItem.text = dishArray[i].name;
        optionItem.setAttribute("value", dishArray[i].id);
        optionItem.setAttribute("data-price", dishArray[i].price);
        optionItem.setAttribute("data-type", dishArray[i].type);
        myDiv.add(optionItem);
    }
}
```

```html
<select class="inputField" id="selectTopping0" ></select>
```

Instead of

```
myDiv.add(optionItem);
```

Use this:

```
myDiv.appendChild(optionItem);
```

Just try it. Hope it will work

Comment: Baka declaration ng script maam or block scoping. Test mo sa console. lagay mo name ng function if accessible sya. then yung json file mo.

Comment: naginput ko sa console initCustomizeBentoScreen() lumabas po sya. how do i fix this sa file ko? T.T

Comment: May email ka? Send ko sayo tong file. For reference mo.

Comment: Sinend ko na. Baguhin mo nalang. Better to check always your script (trailing comma). Indentation. Importante yan maam.

Answer (score 0):

please set sequance of js file
first file is  bentoMain.js make array globle
second file is bentoCustomize.js